# What will be the maximum width of tablet to use in media query?

Tags: android, html, css, media-queries

I did some research on media queries and I am quite confused to get the tablet width.

Some examples I have found:

```
# Mobile
only screen and (min-width: 480px)

# Tablet
only screen and (min-width: 768px) 

# Desktop
only screen and (min-width: 992px)

# Huge
only screen and (min-width: 1280px)
```

But, nowadays tablets sizes are vary. Some tablets looks very large, so how can I find the maximum width of tablet?

So far I used like below..

```
# Tablet
    only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)
```

I need to know the maximum tablet width to fix my responsive design.
And can I use minimum width of 786px for tablet?
I am asking for all branded tablet devices (Samsung, ipad, Google Nexus series)

Comment: try to use @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px), since the landscape screen size will be 1024px and it may suit the normal desktop screen too!!

Comment: your approach should be design-based and not device-based. From a design perspective is it really important if a 768px wide device is a narrow desktop or a tablet?

Comment: So, what you are concluding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I am currently using.

```
   /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 321px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (max-width : 320px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Tablet (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Tablet (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : landscape) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Tablet (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 1224px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Large screens ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 1824px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPhone 4 ----------- */
    @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    /* Styles */
    }
```

Comment: So for tablet min-width - 767px and max-width - 979px right?

Comment: This maximum width 979px is applicable for landscape mode?

Comment: @DineshKumar I had a look at a past project, I have edited my answer. Now you have listed portrait and landscape dimension. I hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Today there are also Phablets and pixel density could be whatever (you can have full hd on 4" phones), so I'd suggest forget about targeting tablets, but rather use relative device with with min-width.

According to older measurement by Quircksmode
http://quirksmode.org/tablets.html

```
@media screen and (min-width: 37em) {
}
```

however, this doesn't work best for newer tablets I guess, since my phone has 37em or more.

Therefore, I'd suggest using

```
@media screen and (min-width: 42em) {
}
```

Unless someone came to the better approach.